# Pandas how to rename existing index and merge it with another one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this

[image: example]

and I want to have an output like this :

[image: output]

There are 53k Rows , and there are many Rows like that , How can I filter them and re-organize them?

Comment: this isn't a one trick solution, you'll need to do some text cleaning or use some sort of natural language processing. Also please take the time to read the rules on SO - see [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                              'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})

df.index = df.Animal #updating the index for illustration purposes

df.groupby(df.index).agg(sum)
```

this will not, however, account for discrepancies in naming. Like one of your Nike is capital and the other is lowercase. You can take care of that by converting everything to lowercase and then aggregating. You can add an extra step for that, like this:

```
df.index = df.index.str.lower()
```

Comment: Sorry , this might sound really dumb, but how do I apply that? Could you make an example? Thank you

Comment: Its okayy, no stress. I've included an example from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with df dataframe :

```
df.columns = ['num', 'brand']
df.groupby('num').filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1).drop_duplicates(subset=['num'],keep="first")
```